# How do I insert a variable into ion-textarea with typescript without using ngModel

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to add the text results of a method called by (click)="runMatrix()" on line 4 into ion-textarea on line 7.  Normally I would use an ngModel, but I cannot in this case as I am using ngModel to save the data.

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let fromItem of importQuestions let i = index">
  <ion-card>  
    <ion-card-content>
      <div class="question_link" (click)="openMatrix()">
      {{fromItem.Question}}
      </div>          
      <ion-textarea auto-grow="true" id="fromItem.ID" name="{{fromItem.name}}" [(ngModel)]="fromItem.input""> </ion-textarea>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      <div class="question">
        {{fromItem.Question}}
      </div>
      <ion-select multiple="true" name="{{fromItem.name}}" [(ngModel)]="fromItem.input">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of importQuestions[i].values" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.value}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card> 
</div>
```

The (click)="runMatrix() method returns a string

```
 this.resultNumber
```

I did not include the method as it is quite large.

How would I get the resultNumber into the input text area of of the ion-textarea after running the method?

Comment: this question is bit confusing can you make it simple ?

Comment: could you please tell did my answer help?

Comment: No sorry. I may have asked the question poorly. The runMatrix() returns something like “some text here”. I have to figure away to get that into the input field of the textarea. I cannot use the index or ngModel as they are being used to pull and save data

Comment: You want to add like this one <ion-textarea>"some string returned by runMatrix"</ion-textare>

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do

Comment: Whatever the code I written that will work. If you change any ngModel value data it will automatically changes in html also.

Comment: ion-text area is inside a loop which means you are having an array of form. If you want access that we need to do based on index only. ngModel is a two way data binding. Once you change it's value in ts file it will automatically saves & updates in html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think on line 4 it should be runMatrix() as you mentioned(In question it was openMatrix). On line 4 make change as below.

```
// passing index no to runMatrix
<div class="question_link" (click)="openMatrix(i)">
```

In your runMatrix() method get the index number make change as below.

```
runMatrix(index) {
     // your logic here 
     // adding updated value to the specific index no.of importQuestions
     this.importQuestions[index].input = "yourResultNumber"
}
```

Comment: I will mark this as a right answer as the fourth line in runMatrix has me working on a solution that will work